# Advanced SQL query in querybuilder symfony2

Tags: mysql, symfony

My Table is "statistic" and columns:

```
Id | user | date | product | number
```

Example data:

```
1 | 1 | 29-11-2016 | 1 | 4
2 | 1 | 30-11-2016 | 1 | 3
3 | 2 | 30-11-2016 | 1 | 2
4 | 2 | 1-12-2016 | 1 | 2
```

Now I want to get average from some first number(x) order by date for any user and where product = 1.

If x = 1 this data query should return 3 (avg where id 1 and 3)
if x = 2 this data query should return 2,75 (avg where id = 1,2,3 and )

Is it possible to do it in one query?

Answer (score 0):

Your raw query should be:

```
select avg(number) as average, user, date from statistic
where product = 1
order by date asc
group by user
```

In querybuilder:

```
$query = $this->createQueryBuilder('s');
$query->select('AVG(s.number) as average, s.user, s.date')
    ->where('s.product = :product')
    ->setParameter('product', $product)
    ->addGroupBy('s.user')
    ->addOrderBy('s.date', 'asc');

//result will be an array
$result = $query->getQuery()->getResult();
```

Comment: Thank you but I want to only x number  the oldest statistic for product and user :) If I want only first (x =1) than I want to get statistic from 29-11-2016 (user 1) and 30-11-2016 (user 2).

Comment: sorry this was not clear in your question. Let me see.